# showing only two out of three cards in my dashboard

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I am creating the dashboard view for my CRM. However while displaying the card view, only two of the three card views are visible. Can anyone help me regarding this? Is this a code formatting issue?

I am adding an image of the dashboard for my CRM below as well as the code for the cards given below.

[image: Dashboard view for my CRM]

example.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">

  <!-- Page Heading -->
  <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4 mt-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Welcome to NexCRM</h1>
    <a href="#" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-download fa-sm text-white-50"></i> Generate Report</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Main Content Here -->
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Company Card Example -->
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
            <div class="col mr-2">
              <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Companies</div>
              <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">4,083</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <i class="fas fa-building fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Company Card Example -->
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
            <div class="col mr-2">
              <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Companies</div>
              <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">4,083</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <i class="fas fa-building fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Contact Card Example -->
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <div class="card border-left-warning shadow h-100 py-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
            <div class="col mr-2">
              <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning text-uppercase mb-1">Contacts</div>
              <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">18,002</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <i class="fas fa-comments fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Content Row -->

  <div class="row">

    <!-- Area Chart -->
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
        <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Earnings Overview</h6>
          <div class="dropdown no-arrow">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-sm fa-fw text-gray-400"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--fade-in" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
              <div class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header:</div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Card Body -->
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="chart-area">
            <canvas id="myAreaChart"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Pie Chart -->
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5">
      <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
        <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Revenue Sources</h6>
          <div class="dropdown no-arrow">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-sm fa-fw text-gray-400"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--fade-in" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
              <div class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header:</div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Card Body -->
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="chart-pie pt-4 pb-2">
            <canvas id="myPieChart"></canvas>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-4 text-center small">
            <span class="mr-2">
                      <i class="fas fa-circle text-primary"></i> Direct
                    </span>
            <span class="mr-2">
                      <i class="fas fa-circle text-success"></i> Social
                    </span>
            <span class="mr-2">
                      <i class="fas fa-circle text-info"></i> Referral
                    </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

```
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It would be MUCH easier if you clicked [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61641571/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and removed the templating and just posted HTML and CSS

Comment: I made you a snippet. As you can see the html you posted works so there must be something else with overflow:hidden or similar

Comment: I have just done that. Thank you.